# Python|Pandas Dataframe | How to remove the lines from a text following a format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file and i want to remove the specific lines.
Example :

first line  ---> timestamp1
second line ---> Name of the person1
third line

first line ---> timestamp2
second line ---> Name of the person2
third line

first line ---> timestamp3
second line ---> Name of the person3
third line

I want to remove the first line and second line from  the complete text file, as the first line & second line follows similar pattern.

I am able to remove the first line which is a time stamp at one go (below is the code)but want to remove the second line too at one go. Appreciate for the help.

First line remove code:

```
#Text(it is the text) loaded in dataframe( df) and then removed the first line:

df = df[~df['Text'].astype(str).str.startswith('0')]
```

Comment: Please add some of your actual data, e.g. using `df.head()`.

Answer (score 0):

If need remove next row after match condition chain by `&` for bitwise `AND` mask by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
#by sample data
m = df['Text'].astype(str).str.startswith('timestamp')
df = df[~m & ~m.shift(fill_value=False)]
```

---

```
print (df)

         Text
2  third line
5  third line
8  third line
```

Your code:

```
m = df['Text'].astype(str).str.startswith('0')
df = df[~m & ~m.shift(fill_value=False)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response.  the suggested code helped

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can preprocess the text before create your dataframe:

```
data = []

with open('data.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith('0'):
            next(fp)  # skip name of person
        elif line:
            data.append(line)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Text'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     Text
0  Text 1
1  Text 2
2  Text 3
```

Input file:

```
>>> %cat data.txt
0123
Louis
Text 1

0456
Paul
Text 2

0789
Alex
Text 3
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response.  the suggested code helped